# $z=0$ is not a local maximum of $|p(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I show that $z=0$ is not a local maximum of $|p(z)|$ where $p(z)=a_0+a_1z+\cdots+a_nz^n$ if $a_i \neq 0$ for some $i>0$.

**My try:** We want to find $z$ in some $\epsilon$ neighbourhood such that $|p(z)| > |a_0|$. But how to construct one?

Comment: What about $y=|p(z)|=|1-z^2|$?

Comment: @EmilioNovati Sorry, I forgot one condition.

Comment: @EmilioNovati:  If $z = ir$, $0 \ne r \in \Bbb R$, then $z^2 = -r^2$, so $\vert 1 - z^2 \vert = \vert 1 + r^2 \vert > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** use the [maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle)

Answer (score 0):

$p(z) = \displaystyle \sum_0^n a_i z^i; \tag 0$

First of all, we can safely assume

$a_0 \ne 0; \tag 1$

for if

$a_0 = 0, \tag 2$

then, since $a_i \ne 0$ for some $i$, $1 \le i \le n$, the polynomial

$q(z) = \displaystyle \sum_1^n a_i z^i \tag 3$

clearly satisfies

$\vert p(0) \vert = \vert q(0) \vert = 0, \tag 4$

and takes on non-zero values arbitrarily close to the point $z = 0$ (which in fact follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, since $q(z) = 0$ for only a *finite* number of $z \in \Bbb C$).  Thus in any neighborhood of $0$ we may find $z_0$ with

$\vert q(z_0) \vert > 0, \tag 5$

so $0$ cannot be a local maximum of

$p(z) = q(z) \; (a_0 = 0). \tag 6$

We can actually take a step or two further in an engaging direction: let $k$ be the least index for which $a_k \ne 0$; with $a_0 = 0$, $k \ge 1$.  Then we may write

$q(z) = z^k \displaystyle \sum_{i = k}^n a_i z^{i - k}, \tag 7$

whence

$\vert q(z) \vert = \vert z \vert^k \left \vert \displaystyle \sum_k^n a_i z^{i -k} \right \vert =  \vert z \vert^k \left \vert a_k + \displaystyle \sum_{k + 1}^n a_i z^{i -k} \right \vert \ge \vert z \vert^k \left \vert \vert a_k \vert - \left \vert \displaystyle \sum_{k + 1}^n a_i z^{i -k} \right \vert \right \vert; \tag 8$

taking $z$ in a sufficiently small disk $D$  centered at $0$ we may ensure that

$\left \vert \displaystyle \sum_{k + 1}^n a_i z^{i -k} \right \vert < \epsilon \tag 9$

for any real $\epsilon > 0$, by the continuity of $\sum_{k + 1}^n a_i z^{i -k}$; in particular, with $\epsilon < \vert a_k \vert$ we find

$\vert q(z) \vert \ge \vert \vert a_k \vert - \epsilon \vert \vert z \vert^k > \vert q(0) \vert = 0 \; \text{when} \; z \in D \setminus \{0\}, \tag{10}$

showing even more forcefully that $0$ is not a local maximum of $\vert q(z) \vert$.

We return to take up the case (1); we may then write $a_0$ as

$a_0 = \vert a_0 \vert e^{i\theta}, \; \theta = \arg(a_0); \tag{11}$

we note that

$\vert e^{-i\theta} p(z) \vert = \vert e^{-i\theta} \vert \vert p(z) \vert = \vert p(z) \vert, \tag{12}$

and that the constant term of $e^{-i\theta}p(z)$ is

$e^{-i\theta}a_0 = e^{-i\theta}e^{i\theta} \vert a_0 \vert = \vert a_0 \vert >0, \tag{13}$

that is, $e^{-i\theta}a_0$ is a positive real.  Now we set

$q(z) = e^{-i\theta} p(z); \tag{14}$

from (12),

$\vert q(z) \vert = \vert p(z) \vert, \tag{15}$

so if we show $0$ is not a local maximum of $\vert q(z) \vert$, we have also shown the same of $\vert p(z) \vert$.

We consider the polynomial $q(z) - \vert a_0 \vert$; the constant term of $q(z)$ is $\vert a_0 \vert$, so

$\vert q(0) - \vert a_0 \vert \vert = 0; \tag{16}$

since $q(z) - \vert a_0 \vert$ is entire, being a polynomial, we may invoke the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)) an affirm that, for every open disk $D(0, \delta)$ centered at $0$, the set

$q(D(0, \delta)) - \vert a_0 \vert  = (q - \vert a_0 \vert)(D(0, \delta)) \tag{17}$

contains, for some $\epsilon > 0$, the disk $D(0, \epsilon)$:

$D(0, \epsilon) \subset (q - \vert a_0 \vert)(D(0, \delta)); \tag{18}$

therefore for any real $0 < r \in D(0, \epsilon)$ we may find

$z_r \in D(0, \delta) \tag{19}$

such that

$q(z_r) - \vert a_0 \vert = r, \tag{20}$

or

$\vert p(z_r) \vert = \vert q(z_r) \vert = q(z_r) = \vert a_0 \vert + r > \vert a_0 \vert = \vert q(0) \vert = \vert p(0) \vert, \tag{21}$

which shows that $0$ cannot be a local maximum for $p(z)$.

***A Few Remarks:***  first, the device of multiplying $p(z)$ by $e^{-i\theta}$ to obtain $q(z)$ with positive real constant term is not really essential to our argument; we could just as well leave $p(z)$ with its constant term unmodified and then look for $z_r$ with $p(z_r) = r a_0$ with $r > 0$ so that

$p(z_r) - a_0 = ra_0 \tag{22}$

and (21) reads

$\vert p(z_r) \vert = \vert a_0  + a_0 r \vert = (1 + r)\vert a_0 \vert > \vert a_0 \vert = \vert p(0) \vert, \tag{23}$

yet again establishing the requisite result.  In the above, I changed $a_0$ into a positive real because I find in a little easier to conceptualize "greater than" in the context of positive reals than of complex numbers with (potentially) arbitrary phase, but that maneuver is not really essential, as has been seen in these *Remarks*.  Of greater significance perhaps is the observation that this result may be significantly generalized to the case $p(z) \in H(\Omega)$ where $\Omega \subset \Bbb C$ is open; then no $z_0 \in \Omega$ is a local maximum of $\vert p(z) \vert$; this may be proved in through an argument quite like that given above, ***viz.*** we may locally develop $p(z)$ as a power series in $z - z_0$:

$p(z) = \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty a_i (z - z_0)^i, \tag{24}$

whence

$p(z) - a_0 =  \displaystyle \sum_1^\infty a_i  (z - z_0)^i; \tag{25}$

since $\vert p(z_0) - a_0 \vert = p(z_0) - a_0 = 0$, we may again apply the open mapping theorem theorem to the holomorphic function $\sum_1^\infty a_i (z - z_0)^i$ and thus affirm the existence, for sufficiently small $r > 0$, of $z_r \in D(z_0, \delta)$ with

$p(z_r) - a_0 = \displaystyle \sum_1^\infty a_i (z_r - z_0)^i = ra_0; \tag{26}$

then

$\vert p(z_r) \vert = (1 + r) \vert a_0 \vert > \vert a_0 \vert = \vert p(z_0) \vert, \tag{27}$

and $z_0$ is not a local maximum of $\vert p(z) \vert$.  Undoubtedly the reader familiar with results such as the open mapping theorem, the maximum modulus principle, and so forth, will recognize the assertions herein demonstrated as applications of these central notions of complex analysis.  Finally, writing in a manner similar to (7),

$p(z) - a_0 = (z - z_0)^k \displaystyle \sum_{k + 1}^\infty a_i(z - z_0)^{i - k}, \tag{28}$

it follows that

$\vert p(z) - a_0 \vert \ge \vert z - z_0 \vert^k \vert \vert a_k \vert - \vert \displaystyle \sum_{k + 1}^\infty a_iz^{i - k} \vert \vert \ge \vert z - z_0 \vert^k \vert \vert a_k \vert - \epsilon \vert, \tag{29}$

for $z - z_0$ sufficiently small.  I know of no way, however, to use (29) by itself to show that $z_0$ is not a local maximum, since even though we may use it to infer the distance 'twixt $p(z)$ and $a_0$ grows with $\vert z - z_0 \vert$, it doesn't inform us as to the *direction* away from $a_0$ in which $p(z)$ lies, so it seems an affirmation such as (26), (27) can't be had from (29) alone, and we must invoke something like the open mapping theorem to establish the existence of $z_r$.  ***End of Remarks.***

[$z=0$ is not a local maximum of $|p(z)|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2956966/z-0-is-not-a-local-maximum-of-pz)